# Jenkins can't find git on Windows node (Linux master)

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

I've got Jenkins running in an EC2 instance on Linux. I have a separate EC2 Windows instance that I'm tying to use as the node/agent for executing my pipeline (it has to be Windows for reasons outside of my control).

I've configured a separate Git tool path for Windows like so (Manage Jenkins > Tools):
[image: DefaultWindows Git tool path specification]

I've configured my node to use that Git path like so (Manage Jenkins > Nodes > Win-Build-Srv > Configure):
[image: Git tool spec on node]

I've verified that the path listed above is correct relative to the Windows agent and that `c:\Git\bin` is in the PATH var on the Windows server. I've even tried manually specifying the PATH var for the windows node:
[image: Windows node PATH manual specification]

Whenever I try to execute the pipeline, it fails to clone the code on the Windows agent, failing with:

```
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
...
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command: /usr/bin/git init c:\workspace\demo_app
```

It is able to do the initial clone on the Jenkins master (Linux) to read the Jenkinsfile, but it always fails when trying to actually execute the pipeline on the Windows node.

I really hope I'm missing something simple, but I've been fighting with this all day and I'm pulling my hair out. Any ideas or suggestions on what to look into would be greatly appreciated.